# Assigning letter to a drive using autorun

Tags: drive-letter, guid

I have an external drive which, for unavoidable reasons, needs to be assigned the same letter, regardless of the computer where I plug it in to. I thought that it could be accomplished by a Diskpart script. I know the GUID of the partition, but how do I select the hard disk in Diskpart using the GUID? Or is there any other way to assign a letter to the hard disk using a script?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to get from a guid to a volume. Diskpart does not appear to display guids at all, either at the partition or volume level, so even if you wrote a powershell script to select each disk, and then select each partition, you could not match it to the known GUID. The only thing I can suggest is that you attempt to match your disk based on Label (it appears to be the only identifying info you can get on a volume), and parse out the volume number. then you can use select volume n where n is the parsed volume number. that way you dont need to select disks/parts at all.

Comment: Can mountvol be used to assign the letter using GUID?

Comment: it looks like mountvol can use the guid, using the Volumename argument, and concatenating the GUID in, but mountvol will not mount at a drive letter, but at an existing path. you cannot specify an unmounted target path for mounting the volume.  If that is fine by you, then it should work. see more here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490934.aspx

Comment: @MycroftHolmes: Can you install a program/service on each computer the drive will be plugged into?

Comment: @Karan: Installing a program would leave an unnecessary footprint on the system. I've tried to achieve the solution using the batch script I posted. It, of course, requires admin privileges though. Kindly go through the script, if you please. Any pointer to enhance the code would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that Windows does remember drive letter assignments until they are overwritten, so if you plug a certain drive and manually assign it the letter K for instance, then ordinarily unless K is the next available drive letter Windows will not assign it to any other drive, but remember it for that particular drive.

Comment: True. But if there are several external hard disks and pendrives used simultaneously, the drive letters tend to get assigned to a different volume. What my script does is to snatch it back, even if it is occupied by some other volume. It is a dangerous practice though, if any process is locking that volume.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "until they are overwritten", but if you assign something like Z for example then unless you exhaust all the rest Windows shouldn't overwrite the setting, and so you can be reasonably assured in that case. A script would ensure the drive letter however, definitely. This is an X-Y problem though, because while the workaround may work the real issue is what requires the same drive letter to be used every time?

Comment: The reason is I'm using some backup softwares which requires the correct drive letter of the external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also made a Powershell script to do the same job. Powershell does a better job than the batch script.

```
$driveI = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter='I:'"

if ($driveI -eq $null)  {

    write-host "I: is free..."

}   elseif ($driveI.DeviceID.Contains("7899c0f7-f556-11e4-9cf2-7071bc4ab2b5") -And  "$drive.SerialNumber = '-1675536360'")    {

    write-host "I: is already assigned to the required disk..."
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    exit

}   else    {    
    write-host "I: is occupied..."
    foreach ( $s in @("'Z:'", "'Y:'", "'X:'", "'W:'", "'V:'", "'U:'", "'T:'", "'R:'", "'Q:'", "'P:'", "'O:'", "'N:'", "'M:'", "'L:'", "'K:'", "'J:'", "'H:'", "'G:'", "'F:'", "'E:'", "'D:'", "'B:'", "'A:'"))
    {
        $testdrv = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter=$s"

        if ($testdrv -eq $null)
        {
            $s = $s.Trim([char]0x0027)
            Set-WmiInstance -input $driveI -Arguments @{DriveLetter=$s}
            Write-Host I: has been moved to $s
            break
        }
    }
}

$diary = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "Label='My Diary'"
if ($diary.DeviceID.Contains("7899c0f7-f556-11e4-9cf2-7071bc4ab2b5") -And  "$diary.SerialNumber = '-1675536360'")
{
    Set-WmiInstance -input $diary -Arguments @{DriveLetter="I:"}
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    exit

}   else    {

    Write-Host Error Occured!
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    exit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the batch file I've written to change the volume letter to K. Any help to enhance the code would be greatly appreciated.

PS. There's a part of code at the beginning to run this using admin privileges. I've omitted that intentionally.

```
:mainBody
set "volume=\Volume{8bc9f784-9f15-11e4-be58-a60f30d14122}"
set "drive="

for %%D in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
mountvol %%D: /L | findstr "%volume%" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
if %%D==K (
echo DONE!
goto end
) else (
set "drive=%%D"
goto clearK
)
)
)

:clearK
mountvol K: /L >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
echo K: is free...
) else (
echo K: is taken...
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('mountvol K: \L') do SET currdriveguid=%%A
for %%D in ( Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J H G F E D B A ) do (
mountvol %%D: /L >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
mountvol K: /d
mountvol %%D:\ currdriveguid
echo Current Volume moved to %%D:...
goto assignK
)
)
)


: assignK
if not defined drive (
mountvol K:\ \\?%volume%\
) else (
mountvol %drive%: /D
mountvol K:\ \\?%volume%\
)

:end
```